# Dovecot and virtual domains with different namespaces

Tags: linux, email-server, dovecot

I've got dovecot 2.1.7 setup with virtual domains and now would like to have different public namespaces for each of the virtual domains.

E.g.

```
workdomain.com
-> INBOX (private namespace)
-> projects (public namespace)
-> customers (public namespace)

fundomain.com
-> INBOx (private namespace)
-> funmails (public namespace)
```

Currently my configuration is

```
namespace inbox {
  type = private
  separator = /
  prefix = INBOX/
  inbox = yes
  location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n

  [..]
}

namespace {
  type = public
  separator = /
  prefix = Public/
  location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/public

  [..]
}
```

... meaning that I have a "Public/" namespace for each virtual domain. So, I'd be looking for something like

```
if workdomain.com {
  namespace { A }
  namespace { B }
}

if fundomain.com {
  namespace { A }
  namespace { C }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
  Ralph

Comment: did you solve your issue? We are looking for the same...